# Edge not displaying properly

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have a propblem with Edge, can't think of a solution. I have a news section and for some reason Edge is displaying old news from May. Clearing cashe doesn't help, all other browsers display news from June and July. I wonder if anyone has come across with this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're expecting here. There's nothing to go on.

Comment: Can you please inform us, about which news you are talking in your description? Is it any specific web site? Which exact version of Edge you are using for making this test? Are there any steps to reproduce the issue? If yes, please inform us, we will try to check the issue. Thanks for your understanding.